# ¿Como leer columnas vacias de un archivo de excel?

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda con un problema, estoy haciendo una aplicacion en java(netBeans) el cual lee un archvo xlxs de excel y lo inserta a una tabla en MySQL el archivo de excel trae 12 columnas y de esas 12 columnas 1 viene vacia osea sin datos. El problema es que cuando inserta en la tabla de MySQL en la columna que viene vacia inserta los datos de la siguiente columna osea que la que se queda vacia es la ultima columna y no la que viene vacia en excel

Comment: Hola Daniel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, _debería_ dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayúdanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto; no explica qué se está haciendo, por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista sobre como vas a lograr tu objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo más de información, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un __[mcve]__ en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 2):

Hola falta que especifiques que libreria estás usando, si es Apache Poi, prueba con esto:

```
for(Row row : sheet) {
   for(int cn=0; cn<row.getLastCellNum(); cn++) {

     // Si falta la celda del archivo, genera una casilla en blanco
     // (Funciona especificando un MissingCellPolicy)
       Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);


       // Imprimir la celda para depurar
       System.out.println("CELL: " + cn + " --> " + cell.toString());
   }
}
```

<sub>**Rerefencia**: [Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells) en [*Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features*](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).</sub>

Comment: Si es con apache poi, ya inserta correctamente, muchas gracias vos

Comment: Por nada, un gusto, si la respuesta fue satisfactoria, marcala como aceptada para futuras consultas de usuarios. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que ya tienes la hoja, te anexo con detalle la información.

1.- Necesitas primero la librería de Java, la puedes descargar desde aquí.

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxljar.htm
```

2.- Incorporas el archivo Excel

Seleccionas el botón derecho sobre la carpeta del proyecto\Propiedades; opción "Java Build Path"; pestaña Librerías; finalmente pulsamos en "Add External JAR" y seleccionamos el archivo.

Este es un ejemplo, a ver que te parece.

**Recorre cada hoja del archivo excel. Dentro de cada hoja, recorre todas las columnas de cada fila del archivo excel y muestra su contenido en pantalla.**

```
importjxl. *;
importjava.io. *; 



public class LeerExcel {

    private void leerArchivoExcel(String archivoDestino) {

        try {
            Workbook archivoExcel = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(
                    archivoDestino));
            System.out.println("Número de Hojas\t"
                    + archivoExcel.getNumberOfSheets());
            for (int sheetNo = 0; sheetNo < archivoExcel.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetNo++) // Recorre las hojas                                                                                                                                                       
            {
                Sheet hoja = archivoExcel.getSheet(sheetNo);
                int numColumnas = hoja.getColumns();
                int numFilas = hoja.getRows();
                String data;
                System.out.println("Nombre de la Hoja\t"
                        + archivoExcel.getSheet(sheetNo).getName());
                for (int fila = 0; fila < numFilas; fila++) { // Recorre cada 
                    // fila de la 
                    // hoja 
                    for (int columna = 0; columna < numColumnas; columna++) {
                        // Recorre                                                                                
                        // cada                                                                                
                        // columna                                                                            
                        // de                                                                                
                        // la                                                                                
                        // fila 
                        data = hoja.getCell(columna, fila).getContents();
                        System.out.print(data + " ");

                    }
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        ReadExcel excel = new ReadExcel();
        excel.leerArchivoExcel("archivoPrueba.xls");
    }
}
```